# How can I create a temporary random TrueCrypt container via the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, truecrypt

I want to build a shell script which will use TrueCrypt to create a temporary, one-time use container with a random key file to be used for scratch space. Basically I want the equivilent of a [Linux tmpfs mount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) (with encrypted swap), but for Mac OS X.

How can I generate a TrueCrypt volume with a random key file under Mac OS X?

Comment: How do you plan to generate the random key?  creating a TrueCrypt container is easy enough but when you mention "random" key that indicates an unecrypted text file that contains your key which does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: `dd if=/dev/urandom of=temp_keyfile bs=1 count=2048` would work.

Comment: @Ramhound see my answer for what I was trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

The following commands will create a TrueCrypt volume with a random key file on the device `$DEVPATH`, * completely overwriting any information on that disk/device!!!* It will then attach the TrueCrypt container, create an HFS+ format volume on this device, and destroy the key it used to create it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Source for random data. Use /dev/random for more secure but slower random data""
RAND=/dev/urandom

# Create a random keyfile:
KEYFILE=/tmp/scratch.key
dd if=$RAND of=$KEYFILE bs=1 count=4096

# Create a TrueCrypt volume on $DEVPATH using $KEYFIlE as the keyfile:
/Applications/TrueCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/TrueCrypt -t -c \
  -k $KEYFILE --volume-type=normal --quick --encryption=AES \
  --hash=RIPEMD-160 --filesystem="none" --password="" \
  --random-source=$RAND $DEVPATH

# Attach the TrueCrypt volume as a device:
/Applications/TrueCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/TrueCrypt -t --mount \
    -k $KEYFILE --password="" --protect-hidden=no \
    --filesystem=none $DEVPATH

# Find the TrueCrypt device:
TCDEV=$(/Applications/TrueCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/TrueCrypt -t -l | grep $DEVPATH | cut -d ' ' -f 3)

# Create a filesystem on the TrueCrypt device:
diskutil eraseVolume JHFS+ Scratch $TCDEV

# And destroy the key so this is a one-time use volume:
srm $KEYFILE
```

Note that:

- The TrueCrypt volume that is created uses a *random key file* with no password. The random key file is created by `dd if=$RAND of=$KEYFILE bs=1 count=4096`. Remove that line and point `KEYFILE=` at a static file if you want a reusable container. **BE SURE TO ALSO REMOVE THE LINE:** `srm $KEYFILE` if you do, because that file line **SECURELY ERASES THE KEY FILE!!!***
- The random data for this script comes from the [*non-blocking random source* `/dev/urandom`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random). Change to `RAND=/dev/random` for more security but slowdowns.
- The *device* `$DEVPATH` **WILL BE OVERWRITTEN BY THIS COMMAND!!!!** Be absolutely sure you know what you're doing. To be safe, set `DEVPATH` to a file, like `/tmp/some_file` and append a `--size=nnnn` to the TrueCrypt line which creates the volume, where `nnnn` is the byte size of the file to create. Remove the `--quick` option. This will be much slower.
- This works on Mac OS X. For Linux, use `mkfs.ext3` rather than `diskutil eraseVolume`. Or just use `mount -t tmpfs` and encrypted swap ;-)